# Firebase Dynamic Links whitelisted

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I have an ios app where I use dynamic links to share content with users, for several months dynamic links worked very well and out of nowhere they stopped working. Does anybody know what is it due to?

During this week I changed the firestore rules, could that affect it?

The console gives me this error:

Error Domain=com.firebase.durabledeeplink Code=0 "We could not match param 'https://www.example.com/post?postId=hy48ndmFLMdxydT7mGPq' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project. [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429] [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429]" UserInfo={remoteStatus=INVALID_ARGUMENT, NSLocalizedFailureReason=We could not match param 'https://www.example.com/post?postId=hy48ndmFLMdxydT7mGPq' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project. [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429] [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429], remoteErrorCode=400}

```
    static let scheme = "https"
    static let pathPost = "/post"
    static let postId = "postId"
    static let host = "www.example.com"
    static let pageLink = "https://*****.page.link"
    static let appId = "*****"

static func getShareLinkPost(post: Post, completion: @escaping FirestoreCompletionLink) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            var components = URLComponents()
            components.scheme = scheme
            components.host = host
            components.path = pathPost
            let userIDQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: postId, value: post.id)
            components.queryItems = [userIDQueryItem]
            guard let linkParameter = components.url else {return}
            guard let shareLink = DynamicLinkComponents.init(link: linkParameter, domainURIPrefix: pageLink) else {return}
            if let myBundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {shareLink.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: myBundleID)}
            shareLink.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = appId
            shareLink.socialMetaTagParameters = DynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters()
            shareLink.socialMetaTagParameters?.title = "@\(post.user?.username ?? "")"
            shareLink.socialMetaTagParameters?.imageURL = URL(string: APPICON)
            print(shareLink.link)
            shareLink.shorten { (url, warnings, error) in
                print(error)
                guard let url = url else {return}
                completion(url)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey same is happening with me :( I could not figure out what is causing the issue? I have also updated Allow URLList on Firebase dynamic link page on Firebase console but it had no effect?